# count value when empty will auto insert

Tags: php, mysql

I can't insert my data in mysql when count value in column `No_KP` when row `No_KP` is empty

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ("../Connections/connection_db.php");
    include ("../Connections/db_connect.php");
    $no_kp = '765454104321';
    $id =  '101';

        mysql_select_db($database_connection_db, $connection_db);
        $query_viewAduan = mysql_query("SELECT No_KP, COUNT(*) FROM aduan_tidak_hadir WHERE No_KP LIKE '%".$no_kp."%' GROUP BY No_KP;");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_viewAduan))
            {
                if (!$row['COUNT(*)'])
                {
                    echo 'satu';
                }
                else if ($row['COUNT(*)'] == '1')
                {
                    echo 'dua';
                }
                else if ($row['COUNT(*)'] == '2')
                {
                    echo 'tiga';
                }
            }           

    ?>
```

my problem is that I can't display when the column is empty, but when the column have any value the data it can be displayed

sorry for my poor english...i wanna to update my question...
what i want to do is before i add an value in my database this function will do is count that value what i insert if that value is not inside my database so that this function will add the value inside my database and count it to 1.if that value already at the database this function will count and show it to 2 when the same value insert on second time and also same when the same value insert at the third time will show it to 3

Comment: maybe if ($row['COUNT(*)']=='0') echo 'satu' ?

Comment: try this is_null($row['COUNT(*)'])

Comment: by the way don't use `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated, won't be supported in future php releases, and have serious sql injection vulnerabilities blah blah... xD try `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead!!

Comment: i have never try mysqli_before.can i know what is this?and how this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested: Assume that you want to know if something has been 'echoed' or not...

This line of code...
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query_viewAduan);

$row will be an 'empty' array if 'no rows returned'. Therefore the 'while' loop will not be entered.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ("../Connections/connection_db.php");
    include ("../Connections/db_connect.php");
    $no_kp = '765454104321';
    $id =  '101';

        mysql_select_db($database_connection_db, $connection_db);
        $query_viewAduan = mysql_query("SELECT No_KP, COUNT(*) FROM aduan_tidak_hadir WHERE No_KP LIKE '%".$no_kp."%' GROUP BY No_KP;");
        $somethingEchoed = false;

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_viewAduan))
            {
                $somethingEchoed = true;

                if (!$row['COUNT(*)'])
                {
                    echo 'satu';
                }
                else if ($row['COUNT(*)'] == '1')
                {
                    echo 'dua';
                }
                else if ($row['COUNT(*)'] == '2')
                {
                    echo 'tiga';
                }
            }           

            if (!$somethingEchoed) {
               // do 'nothing echoed' processing here
            }

    ?>
```